# Possible to call 'alert()' or 'console.log()' from Angular ng-click Expression?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I was trying to test if my `ng-click` binding was working -- but I seem to be running into a more-fundamental problem -- how to see what is happening (or not).

My usual 'crude' debugging methods, `alert()` and `console.log()`, do not seem to be available.

Is it possible to get access to these functions or something like them from within an Angular app?

The plnkr example below seems to show the click event 'working' -- effecting objects in my component -- but my function calls to `alert()` and `log()` seem to be getting ignored.

With that said, is there a way to get some kind of error message when I call a probably-nonexistent function? The Chrome console log does not seem to show anything.

https://embed.plnkr.co/Dvadi8mWlUqTUW865UsI/

I think the 'possibly-duplicate' question is similar, but it does not not actually talk about alert() or log() in the title, and the various partial answers seem generally geared towards Angular 1.x and controllers -- I do not have a controller.

So part of this question is -- do I need a controller? It looks like there might be an easy way to 'decorate' my app, but I only have modules and classes right now, no explicit controller.

Thank you.

---

I think the best answer is at bottom -- 'ng-click' must be provided an expression, not a function call.

and here is some properly formatted code to show how to call these basic functions in Angular2 (for other newbies out there):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    //template:`<h2>Hello, world</h2>` ,
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Quiz Tool';
    quiz = new Quiz();

    doAlert(){
        console.log('log: test log, yo...'); // black
        console.debug('debug: test log, yo...'); // blue
        console.warn('warn: test log, yo...'); // yellow
        console.info('info: test log, yo...'); // black (with 'i' icon)
        console.error('error: test log, yo...'); // red
        alert('test...');
    }
}
```

and call the doAlert() method from your HTML:

```
<button (click)="doAlert();count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">Increment</button>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Both of that is basic JS provided tools. It should be available!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does ng-click not work in case-1, but does in case-3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725312/why-does-ng-click-not-work-in-case-1-but-does-in-case-3)

Comment: `alert()` and `console.log()` are part of the global context. JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the `global` window. In AngularJS, expressions are evaluated against a `scope` object.  See [AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions).

Comment: ok, so i'm using Angular2, so no real/explicit controller yet. it seems you can call both these functions from within a function of your component -- somehow they're available there but not in your browser window, i.e. from your DOM/html element -- so write simple wrapper functions and call `doAlert()` and `doLog()`: `@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    doAlert(){
        alert('test...');
    }
    doLog(){    console.log('test log, yo...'); }
}
`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ng-click must be call an expression. AngularJS expressions do not have direct access to global variables like window, document or location. This restriction is intentional. It prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of subtle bugs.

Answer (score 17):

> alert() and console.log(), do not seem to be available.

Both `alert()` and `console.log()` are evaluated against the global `window` object. On the other hand [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) is an AngularJS Expression and is evaluated against the `scope` associated with it which does not have any direct access to the `window` object. Thus they are not available inside `scope`.

[`AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

> **Context:** JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global window. In AngularJS, expressions are evaluated against a scope object.

AngularJS provides a service called `$log` for that purpose. You can use `$log` service like the following:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log){
  $scope.TestClick = function(){
    $log.log('You have clicked');
  }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="button" value="Click" ng-click="TestClick()"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Both of that is basic JS provided tools. It should be available!

If you wish to console or alert from HTML, it probably not a good way to do it. Nor i think it is possible.

You may choose to attach your HTML to a controller and then move the `Console.log` or `alert` to that controller. And It will work as expected.

---

> ### AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions
>
> AngularJS expressions are like JavaScript expressions with the following differences:
>
> - **Context:** JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the `global` window. In AngularJS, expressions are evaluated against a `scope` object.
>
> [- AngularJS Developer Guide - AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions)

Answer (score 4):

A quick and dirty way to get access to `alert` and `console.log` from within a `(click)` or similar handler, is to alias `alert` and `console` into the `@Component` object:

```
@Component({
  // ...
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
        // ...
        this.console = window.console
        this.alert = window.alert
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `alert` or `console.log` from ng-click, it looks for that method on the $scope or an angular expression, and it's not there.

In your example only `count = count + 1` is expression and others are neither function or expression. That's why only count get increased and console or alerts not working.

If you need to use alerts and console logs then use it inside the scope method.