# Encoding string into url in angular 8

Tags: angular, url

I am writing code to share a link on twitter on clicking the twitter icon
Here is my template

```
<a id="tw" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://publish.therightdoctors.com/posts/{{data2['question_id']}}/{{encodeURIComponent(data2['question'])}}&text={{data2['question']}}&via=TheRightDoctors"
                                                        title="Share on Twitter" data-service="twitter" target="_blank"> <i class="fab fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

In component.ts

```
import { HttpParameterCodec } from "@angular/common/http";
```

But it is giving me error

```
_co.encodeURIComponent is not a function
```

How to solve it?
I tried to write a function in ts. Now there is no error but on compose tweet the link is coming with space like https://publish.therightdoctors.com/posts/1/What is machine learning? but I wanted this https://publish.therightdoctors.com/posts/1/What%20is%20machine%20learning?

Answer (score 0):

Angular is trying to resolve `encodeURIComponent` in the context of the component, not the global javascript context. You need to have a method in your class (.ts) that does it for you, and call it from the template. Such as:

```
myEncodeURIComponent(text: string): string [
    return encodeURIComponent(text);
}
```

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617078/possible-to-call-alert-or-console-log-from-angular-ng-click-expression) see the answer confirmed there too.

Comment: I tried to write a function in ts. Now there is no error but on compose tweet the link is coming with space like https://publish.therightdoctors.com/posts/1/What is machine learning? but I wanted this https://publish.therightdoctors.com/posts/1/What%20is%20machine%20learning?

Comment: @trdwip002 edit your question above and include the function you wrote. Maybe I can help

Comment: @trdwip002 please include the actual function code, the template markup that calls the function, and an example of the input. Without it it's impossible to find the problem

Comment: function is same as in answer and i have changed the function name in template

Comment: @trdwip002 Apparently when enclosed in quoted attribute it does not show the encoded space %20. But for example in `<span>{{ myEncodeURIComponent(text) }}</text>` it does. I don't think your code should break